# Modify Choice Validation in Choice Prompt - Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

Currently having a choice_prompt that asks the user for some options to validate. To move to the next step of the waterfall, the user's input has to either be the value, or a synonym associated with that value.

If a user types something that is not the value or synonym, the choicePrompt just loops. I want to move on to the next waterfell step regardless of what the input is.

```
return await step.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
            prompt: 'What can we help you with today?',
            choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices([
                {value:"Meeting",synonyms:['list1','list2']},
                {value:"Help",synonyms:['Dog','assistance','aid']},
                {value:"Test",synonyms:['please help me','sample','code']},
            ])
        })
```

Any suggestions or parameters to change the validation logic for the inputs?

Comment: Marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

When you add the prompt to the to the dialog set, you can define a custom validation method for the prompt that always return true.

**Bot Framework SDK v4 (Node)**

```
this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, promptContext => true));
```

Hope this helps!